# Replacing 4 Way Switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

Trying to replace [image: this switch] which has 2 white wires, 2 red wires, with [image: this switch], which is labeled with in and out holes.

This is not correct, but I am not sure which way it should go or which wire is which! Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please color all the wires going to that switch yellow using colored electrical tape.  I am serious. It will make this circuit 10 times easier to understand. **I am serious**.  All those wires are *travelers*.  It matters which cable they are grouped in, it matters what screw color they are landed on.  It does not matter if they are red or white, that is a huge red herring/distraction.

Comment: It looks like the querent has the misfortune of having a switch with 4 screws, all the same color?!

Comment: hmm ok, so are you wanting to know how it connects to the switch next to it?

Comment: Can you post a clear photo looking into the back of the switch box?

Comment: @SThomas -- did you catch what I was saying about posting a photo looking into the back of the box?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, Yes, sorry for the delay! Here are the requested pics, hopefully you are able to see what you need to: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kcm83btbbsl15ub/IMG_5072.JPG?dl=0

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel https://www.dropbox.com/s/wlc529tx6lagxt3/IMG_5073.JPG?dl=0

Comment: @SThomas -- what leads you to believe that the wiring of the new switch depicted in your photo is incorrect?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel well, I could not get the light to work properly from all 3 switches!

Comment: @SThomas -- what sort of improper behavior did you observe?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel as an example, this switch will turn the light on and off, but if I try and turn it on at one of the other 2 switches, it does not do anything.

Answer (score 4):

3-way and 4-way circuits are simple. But they're *made* really strange because of the *circumstances by which household wiring is done*.  They're actually quite simple - forehead-slapping simple.

[image]

*How hard is that? Switches line up, light comes on.*

Now a 4-way just goes in the middle between the 3-ways.  It either sends the yellows through straight, or crosses them.  Simple as that.   So what does that look like *in actual wiring*?

[image]

*Disregard the color of the passing-through wire.*

Notice the colored *screws*.   On 3-ways, there are 2 brass and the travelers go to them; black is common.   **On 4-ways, there are 2 brass for one *group* of travelers, and 2 black for the other group.**

How do we tell which travelers are in the same group?  Easy!  They came out of the same cable or conduit!

### Colors: the real devil here

Now I notice you're not using yellow for travelers. Actually, you're using red and white because houses are wired with this stuff:

[image]

Which only comes in the one set of colors - black red white.  And of course you entered this deal *thinking* wires were color-coded for **purpose**.  You were thinking the red/white meant something.  Nope. Installers are stuck with the colors that come in the cable. Sometimes it "works out"; but often - *and always in 3-way circuits* - color coding goes right out the window, and it's *catch as catch can*.

They're only color-coded for purpose **if you code them**. That's why I own 10 colors of electrical tape :)  Mark wires religiously, both ends at the same time.  I'm fond of yellow for travelers since they are interchangeable (as you can see from the top drawing) and there's no need to distinguish one from another.

[image]

Comment: @SThomas, Just one note, the second diagram (with the 4-way) could be misleading. The cables should usually be grouped at the tops and bottoms of these switches, not from the sides. But to be sure you really need to use a continuity tester or meter to figure out the internal relationships of the screws. Sometimes they are black and brass, sometimes all brass. You'll need to figure out which screws make continuity with each other when the switch is in each position. We don't want a loop, we want current to pass through to the next switch in the system.

Comment: @Nicknamednick I tried, but it makes the drawing much more busy and confusing. The lesson is about grouping.  If a 4-way has defective markings, *the first problem is it might not be a 4-way*. Even if it is, UL sure didn't approve it like that!  So it violates 110.2, but mostly is a waste of time for a DIYer struggling with 3ways in the first place.  I'd tell the DIYer "Go get a known good 4-way".  That said, "How do I beep out a suspected 4-way" would be a great question.

Answer (score 0):

Red and white from the same cable attaches to the top screws of the switch.the other set attaches to the bottom screws. If it is a 4 way that is.

Comment: That's not a uniform rule -- one could have a 4-way switch where the wires were turned 90deg from what you describe

Comment: And if that was true then I would answer accordingly to that situation. My answer was in response to what was presented. Clearly nobody asked what this switch actually controlled. The type of box is typical in houses. The fact that the 2 black wires are marretted together is most commonly used in this scenario so that on the end 3 way switch there is a black wire for the common screw.   It would be nice for every electrician to tape wires such that whites are only used for neutrals however every company has their standards to improve efficiency and therefore increase profit.

Comment: Actually it looks like this 4-way switch has the poles catty-corner from each other.  Blacks on opposite corners, brass on the other opposite corners.  Look close at photo 2.